# Cannot SSH to Azure VM

Tags: azure, ssh, virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-vm-role

I have a Ubuntu VM on Azure (Resource Group, not the Classic VM) and it all worked out of the box. I recently tried to SSH into the VM using Putty and I could not.

I get the error: `Network Error: Connection Timed out`.

I have made sure that the port 22 is opened for SSH on the VM Inbound rules.

[image: SSH Port 22 Allowed]

I had this VM setup about 2 months ago for a side project and at that time I was able to SSH easily without any troubles. Now I can't. Am I missing something?

PS: The HTTP works fine. I have the website running on it and it shows up in the browser. Also, I tried using a browser-based SSH client and it was able to SSH into the VM.

Comment: Can you telnet port 22?

Comment: Incase if you haven't checked, try the below troubleshooting steps and see if that helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/troubleshoot-ssh-connection

Comment: this may help for new comers https://devsdaily.com/ssh-port-22-connection-timed-out/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks to be an issue with the local firewall. Try resetting the SSH configuration in the portal.

1. Go to Azure Portal
2. Select VM in question
3. Select Reset
   Password
4. Select Reset Configuration Only
5. Select Update

[image: Screenshot of the process here!]

Comment: This is ridiculous! I was able to SSH into the VM until it stopped by itself, and I had to follow this procedure in order to fix it.

Comment: This issue is still present in 2022 :(

Comment: resetting  ssh config helped

Answer (score 13):

I am adding this because it might help someone, the chosen answer did not work for me

for some reason the firewall on the ubuntu server

Go to `Serial Console` type in your ssh username and you will be logged into the server

Check the firewall status to see if port 22 is allowed

`sudo ufw status verbose`

If the rule is not there then add it

`sudo ufw allow ssh`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. The following is how I solve this issue:

1. **Don't add any port While creating your VM, do it only after only the VM is created**
2. Add the port 22 in the networking tab until the VM status is Running.

Answer (score -1):

When a new VM is created on Azure, by-default the Protocol TCP on Port 22 is Disabled. Need to allow this.

Follow:
https://medium.com/techinpieces/practical-azure-how-to-enable-ssh-on-azure-vm-84d8fba8103e

Comment: They clearly showed in their question that they already did this.

Comment: I think its the priority issue, need to set the default priority 330

Answer (score -3):

Create below directory : `mkdir -p /run/sshd`

Then restart service : `systemctl restart ssh`

This will definitely solve your issue.